# How to numerically fit an adaptive composite bezier curve?

Tags: time-series, curve-fitting, splines, compression

Given a set of points $X$ that define a smoothly varying curve $y$ that describe a highly sampled smoothly varying time series I would like to fit some bezier curve sections to the data to effectively compress it in an online manner (perhaps with a small amount of back tracking. The compression would come from selecting knots that strike a balance between reconstruction error and the path-length of the controlled section of the curve.

Are there any packages (in python) that already do this optimization for # of knots and their positions or will I have to roll my own implementation?